# Linux Mint 19.1 - Hide and show windows shortcut

Tags: linux-mint

Is there a shortcut or command on Linux Mint 19.1 (MATE) to show and hide all windows? `<super> + D` doesn't work, but I know the functionality exists, as the button at the lower left side of the screen works like a charm.

[image]

Comment: This should be Ctrl+Alt+D, found in *Preferences > Hardware > Keyboard and Shortcuts*, or in console `mate-keybinding-properties`, then look for *Window Management > Hide all normal windows and set focus to the Desktop*, where you may change the shortcut.

Comment: Thanks, but pressing Ctrl+Alt+D doesn't work and there isn't a "Window Management" option at Keyboard Shortcuts.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where they stashed it now.